# как прочитать и записать только дату в текстовом файле, если дата находится в конце строки

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

Вопрос по сути следующий, есть задача парсинга входящих писем в виде текстовых файлов на предмет даты их написания, и организаций написавших мне это письмо, есть программа которая позволяет читать только строки, соответственно выводит кроме даты в новый созданный файл всю строку с датой, подскажите как это поправить

```
name: str = input ("Введите имя входящего файла")
f = open (name, "r")  # открываем файл
lines = f.readlines ()  # читаем его построчно
t: str = lines [23] # выводим строки
t1: str = lines [24] # выводим строки
#print(t, t1)
name1: str = input ("Введите имя исходящего файла")
f = open(name1, "w+")
f.write(str(t))
f.write(str(t1))
f.close()
```

В идеале нужно даже немного больше, хотелось бы находить конкретные места написания даты в документе, т.е. сейчас если дата будет написана не в 25 строке то её естественно программка не найдёт.
[image: Красным помечено то что я хотел бы вынимать из писем]

Comment: Приведите примеры писем, из которых вы хотели бы извлекать дату. Вообще можно из библиотеки Natasha взять экстрактор дат.

Comment: В описании добавил пример

Comment: Ага, ну точно Natasha подойдёт. Поищите поиском тут на SO, я как-то давно писал примеры как её нужно применять в таких случаях. Позже сам ещё поищу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы вытащить дату, то циклом пройдись по всем строкам и с помощью простого регулярного выражения найди дату.

```
import re

# шаблон регулярного выражения
# даты формата dd.mm.yyyy или dd/mm/yyyy или dd\mm\yyyy
# Год от 2000 до 2021
date_re = r'[0123]?\d[./\\][01]?\d[./\\]20[012][01]'

# открываем файл
name: str = input ("Введите имя входящего файла")
f = open (name, "r")  
lines = f.readlines()

# В эту переменную сохранится найденная дата
date_str = ''

for line in lines:
  # поиск шаблона в строке
  re_result = re.search(date_re, line)
  # если нашли
  if re_result:
    # сохраняем в переменную и завершаем цикл поиска
    date_str = re_result.group(0)
    break
```

Примерно, так.

Comment: тут не совсем понятно по какому критерию ищется дата, написав этот код в результате в документе появляется "25.0" дальше поиск цифр заканчивается, объясните подробнее что ищет программа

Comment: по-видимому, когда регулярные выражения проверял, скопировал не тот вариант, здесь ошибка осталась, не экранируется символ \. Исправил

Answer (score 0):

Если все документы имеют нужные вам данные на 1 и последней строке, просто берите их от туда

```
name: str = input ("Введите имя входящего файла: ")
f = open (name, "r")  # открываем файл
lines = f.readlines()  # читаем его построчно
t1 = lines[0]
t2 = lines[-1]
name1: str = input ("Введите имя исходящего файла: ")
f = open(name1, "w+")
f.write(str(t1 + "\n" + t2))

f.close()
```

Ну или можете использовать регулярные выражения, как уже написали ниже.